# Disable main window but show module

Tags: java, netbeans, netbeans-platform, javahelp

My goal is to launch a NetBeans platform application without showing the main window. I know its possible and have done so succeessfully by following this tutorial: http://java.dzone.com/news/how-create-a-consoleserver-app

However, I also want to automatically display the HelpSet (from a module). When I follow the tutorial link above, I get the desired result - no splash screen, no main window and HelpSet opens automatically.

However, the Help that opens up is empty!

I can see a warning thrown in the console:

`WARNING [org.netbeans.modules.javahelp]: Warning: the JavaHelp topic ID org.openide.util.HelpCtx.DEFAULT_HELP was not found.`

I am at a loss. The only code I have is this in the Installer.java

```
public class Installer extends ModuleInstall {

    @Override
    public void restored() {
        Help h = Lookup.getDefault().lookup(Help.class);
        if (h != null) {
            h.showHelp(HelpCtx.DEFAULT_HELP);
        }
    }
}
```

You can download my entire NetBeans project here: http://www.mediafire.com/?vkxqbrx9qy4ix1n

When you run it, you'll see that there is no splash, or ide window, but help pops up empty with a warning in console saying it can't find the help.

Thank You